# Toggle css property in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu that slides out on clicking the `nav-toggle` class.

Now I also want the `nav-toggle` class (the menu icon) to move along 226px from the right, so it moves at the same time as the `#navigation` menu. Then if clicked again it will collapse the menu (as it currently does) and go back to `right:0` position.

See my commenting out in the third last line

```
jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        var $marginLefty = jQuery('#navigation');
        $marginLefty.animate({
            right: parseInt($marginLefty.css('right'), 10) == 0 ? -$marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
        jQuery('.nav-toggle').animate({
            right: "226px" 
        // How do I make it so if it is at 226px when clicked
        // it should then go to "right: 0", that toggle effect as above
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Could you include the relevant html aswell? :) EDIT: or a fiddle.. that'll work too.. ;)

Comment: Can you create and post a jsFiddle with your html/css/js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just like you did the `#navigation` one:

```
 jQuery('.nav-toggle').animate({
    right: parseInt(jQuery('.nav_toggle').css('right'), 10) == 0 ? "226px" : 0;
 });
```

Comment: Much cleaner than what I was going to put. +1

Comment: The page isn't loading now :) I'll paste the code here..  `jQuery('.nav-toggle, .nav-close').click(function () {
        var $marginLefty = jQuery('#navigation');
        $marginLefty.animate({
            right: parseInt($marginLefty.css('right'), 10) == 0 ? -$marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
        jQuery('.nav-toggle').animate({
      right: parseInt(jQuery('.nav-toggle').css('right'), 10) == 0 ? "226px" : 0;
   });
 });`

Comment: My fault, sorry an extra `;`

Comment: No problem. Glad you found it.

Comment: Thanks @mavrosxristoforos, much apprciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to check if the nav is expanded/moved or not.

```
var navbar = $('.nav-toggle');    
if (navbar.hasClass('expanded'))
            {
                $(navbar).animate({'right':'226px'}).removeClass('expanded');
            } else {
                $(navbar).animate({'right':'0px'}).addClass('expanded');
            }
```

Note these numbers may need flipping.

Comment: Try again possibly, and try flipping the 226px and the 0px; or make it 'marginLeft'. Otherwise i'm not sure sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
    var $marginLefty = jQuery('#navigation');
    $marginLefty.animate({
        right: parseInt($marginLefty.css('right'), 10) == 0 ? -$marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
    });
    if ($('.nav-toggle').css('right') == '0px') {
        $(".nav-toggle").stop().animate({right: '226px'}, 1000);
    } else {
        $(".nav-toggle").stop().animate({right: '0px'}, 1000);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I want to encapsulate that within the on click function. So if the user clicks on nav-toggle it will not only bring in/out the nav div, but also animate the nav-toggle position. I can't use a button toggle because I'm already using an on click and want to integrate with that.